# Python 3 boto3 loading files to S3 AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to deploy a lambda function to load a file in S3, in a meantime I'm working just to my local environment and here is my code:

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxx'
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxx'
BUCKET_NAME = 'biximontreal'

s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)


for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)

FILE_NAME = 'Bixi_9_16_14-38.json'
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_file(FILE_NAME, BUCKET_NAME, FILE_NAME)
```

At the end of my code everything seems to be executed seamlessly, but when I go to my S3 bucket the file is there with no data:

[image]

the file from my local repository it's not empty:

[image]

Could you guys help me to understand why it's not loading the file with data and also help me to figure it out?

thanks so much

Comment: not has data look at my post!! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out my problem was that I wasn't sending the **body** data as a parameter in my query to load the file with info.

```
x = 'x'
x = 'x'
BUCKET_NAME = 'x'

s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=x,
    aws_secret_access_key=x,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)


filename = 'Bixi_%s_%s_%s-%s.json' % (month, day, hour, mins)
datafile = open('/tmp/Bixi_%s_%s_%s-%s.json' % (month, day, hour, mins),'rb')

s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key=filename, Body=datafile)
```

Thanks everyone.